# How can I permit evaluation of code blocks in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to allow for evaluation of code blocks within a trusted Org mode document (following instructions at https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html) but can't seem to dodge the prompt. Minimal examples:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args: :eval yes

#+begin_src python :results output
print("Hello World")
#+end_src
```

```
#+header: :eval yes
#+begin_src python :results output
print("Hello World")
#+end_src
```

```
#+begin_src python :results output :eval yes
print("Hello World")
#+end_src
```

It seems that in each case, `:eval yes` is ignored and I am prompted:

*Evaluate this python code block on your system? (yes or no)*

I would prefer not to use

```
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
```

(https://orgmode.org/manual/Code-Evaluation-Security.html).

Code evaluation works OK if I answer yes, but I'd prefer not to have to do that when the source is trusted.

I assume I must have the syntax wrong, but am not sure how to fix it.

In `init.el`:

```
...
(org-babel-do-load-languages
    'org-babel-load-languages
    '((emacs-lisp . t)
      (python . t)))
...
```

Emacs 28.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one mistake in the syntax: the name of the property should not end with a colon, so the `#+PROPERTY` line should read:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :eval yes
```

However, that only affects the first of your examples; the other two blocks are unaffected by the syntax error. The fact is that if `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` is at its default value of `t`, they all pop the question. Assuming that you are interpreting the doc correctly, it seems like a bug to me.

Here's the doc of the `:eval` header:

```
The ‘eval’ header argument can limit evaluation of specific code blocks
and ‘CALL’ keyword.  It is useful for protection against evaluating
untrusted code blocks by prompting for a confirmation.

‘yes’
     Org always evaluates the source code without asking permission.
...
```

It seems pretty unequivocal that if the header is `:eval yes` then Org evaluates the block with no questions asked (whatever the value of `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` is). That's the way you interpreted it and I agree with your interpretation.

Unfortunately, the [code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-core.el#n232) does not agree:

```el
  (let* ((headers (nth 2 info))
     (eval (or (cdr  (assq :eval headers))
           (when (assq :noeval headers) "no")))
     ...
     (query (or (equal eval "query")
                (and export (equal eval "query-export"))
                (if (functionp org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
                    (funcall org-confirm-babel-evaluate
                    ;; Language, code block body.
                    (nth 0 info)
                    (org-babel--expand-body info))
                   org-confirm-babel-evaluate))))
```

Even though the value of the `eval` variable is "yes", the `query` variable is set to whatever `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` is set (in the simplest case where it is either `t` or `nil` - but that's the only case we are interested in here). So in the default case where `org-config-babel-evaluate` is `t`, then the `query` value will be `t` as well.

The subsequent `cond` then:

```el
    (cond
     (noeval nil)
     (query 'query)
     (t t))))
```

finds `query` to be `t` and returns the symbol `query` which makes the caller of this function (`org-babel-confirm-evaluate`) pop the dreaded question.

It seems to me that the `query` variable in `org-babel-check-confirm-evaluate` is calculated incorrectly (assuming that the doc means what it says) and that's a bug that should be reported to the Org mode ML.

One possible workaround is to modify the `cond` in `org-babel-check-confirm-evaluate` to check if `eval` is `"yes`" before going on to the `query` case:

```el
    ...
    (cond
     (noeval nil)
     ((equal eval "yes") t)   ; add case to check `eval`
     (query 'query)
     (t t))))
```